# How to looping this function after the last value

Tags: javascript

```
var board = new DepartureBoard(document.getElementById('test'), {
     rowCount: 1,
     letterCount: 13
 });

window.setTimeout(function() {
    board.setValue(['VISA SERVICES', ]);
}, 0)
window.setTimeout(function() {
    board.setValue(['POE CLEARENCE', ]);
}, 8000);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    board.setValue(['STAMPING', ]);
}, 16000);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    board.setValue(['ATTESTATION', ]);
}, 24000);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    board.setValue(['INSURANCE', ]);
}, 32000);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    board.setValue(['FOREX', ]);
}, 40000);
```

https://codepen.io/Mtn_Wolf/pen/LKsvz

I am trying like the Airport departure but i can't able to looping the value after the last value displayed in my website to show services how i can loop the value after the last content displayed

Comment: Do you mean that you want the entire process to run again, over and over?

Comment: Yes, I want to run entire process to run again, over and over without any delay

Comment: Forever? Does it ever need to stop?

Comment: Yes, Need to run forever

Comment: Use setInterval(function, delay) judiciously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you could use an outer interval, which length is the complete period and inside call the smaller timeout for the next actions.

```
function startInterval() {
    window.setTimeout(function() { board.setValue(['VISA SERVICES']); }, 0)
    window.setTimeout(function() { board.setValue(['POE CLEARENCE' ]); }, 8000);
    window.setTimeout(function() { board.setValue(['STAMPING']); }, 16000);
    window.setTimeout(function() { board.setValue(['ATTESTATION']); }, 24000);
    window.setTimeout(function() { board.setValue(['INSURANCE']); }, 32000);
    window.setTimeout(function() { board.setValue(['FOREX']); }, 40000);
}

startInterval();
setInterval(startInterval, 48000); // use the length of the period
```

Answer (score 1):

Using direct timeouts in modern ECMAScript is not good pattern, not just because "modern approach", but because better chaining and error handling

```
function delay(time) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time) }
function worker() {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => board.setValue(['VISA SERVICES']))
        .then(() => delay(1000))
       // and so on
        .then(worker);
}

worker().catch((error) => {
    // Error handling here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could accomplish this, here's my suggestion, which basically keeps your current code intact -

Put all of your calls to `window.setTimeout()` in a function - at the end, add one more call to `window.setTimeout()` that just calls the function, which will start it again.  Something like...

```
var board = new DepartureBoard(document.getElementById('test'), { rowCount: 1, letterCount: 13 });

var myFunction = function(){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        board.setValue(['VISA SERVICES', ]);
    }, 0)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        board.setValue(['POE CLEARENCE', ]);
    }, 8000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        board.setValue(['STAMPING', ]);
    }, 16000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        board.setValue(['ATTESTATION', ]);
    }, 24000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        board.setValue(['INSURANCE', ]);
    }, 32000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        board.setValue(['FOREX', ]);
    }, 40000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        myFunction(); // call it again here, and the process will start over
    }, 50000);
}

myFunction(); // don't forget - now that all of the window.setTimeout calls are wrapped in a function, the process won't start unless you call the function here, setting off the loop
```

Comment: Error coming so I replace the "var myFunction(){" to "function myFunction(){" its working now Thank You

Comment: Oh yes - sorry, that's a typo on my part. I meant to write `var myFunction = function(){...}`... editing...